# Interface Scaling / Independent Resolution per Application on MacBook Pro Retina

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution

I have a MacBook Pro Retina and I run it on the unsupported/non-HiDPI 2560x1600 to be able to work on multiple windows at the same time.

This resolution increases the DPI allowing a large screen real estate. Everything seems fine, i sometimes need to Zoom to a particular window (Ctrl+Scroll) but it's not bothering me.

I find an issue using Microsoft Office (Excel and Word), where I'm constantly having to zoom in at 200% inside the document to be able to read and write.

Pre-Retina, there was an Interface Scale Factor that could be increased System-wide or Application-wide. The Application-wide would let you decrease/increase the DPI per application such as iTunes or Safari.

The command was something similar to:

> defaults write /theapp/ AppleDisplayScaleFactor 0.85

This command doesn't seem to work on my system (Retina/Mavericks)

My question is whether it exists something similar for my Retina (Mavericks)? 
Basically I want to increase the Scale Factor/Independent Resolution/DPI per Application and try to get the UI of Office (or other applications) to be larger, which would help a lot in a 2500x1600 world.

Thank you,